# Pass a C++ child class member function (virtual implementation) to a C-type function pointer

Tags: c++

I have searched and seen many SO answers relating this topic, but none of them have worked for my case. I must pass a C-type function pointer to a function of a library I'm using. Here's a short description:

**baseClass.h**

```
Class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual lib_returnType capabilityImplementation(lib_type input_1, ..., lib_type input_11) = 0;

    bool performLocalCheckFct(...){ /* perform check */ }

    lib_returnType methodCallback(lib_type input_1, ..., lib_type input_11)
    {
        if(performLocalCheckFct(...)== true)
        {
            return capabilityImplementation(input_1, ..., input_11);
        }
    }
    /* something else */
protected:
    /* some data */
}
```

I use this base class to implement other use-case specific child classes which have the same structure but implement the *capabilityImplementation* function differently:

**ChildClass_1.h**

```
Class ChildClass_1 : public BaseClass
{
public:
    ChildClass_1(){ /* modify base class protected data */ }

    lib_returnType capabilityImplementation(lib_type input_1, ..., lib_type input_11)
    { /* do something */ }
}
```

The C-callback is **required** in the ***createMacaroni*-method** inside the "ImplementationClass" :

**ImplementationClass.h**

```
typedef lib_returnType (*c_type_FC)(lib_type, ..., lib_type);

Class HandlerClass{
public:
    HandlerClass(lib_type input_1){
        initializeHashMap();
        /* do something else */
    }

    initializeHashMap(){
        childHashTable["myChild1"] = std::make_shared<ChildClass_1>();
        /*... e.g. 50 different child classes */
        childHashTable["myChild50"] = std::make_shared<ChildClass_50>();
    }

    bool createMacaroni(std::string childClassName) {
        /* do stuff */
        /* perform C-type function pointer binding here*/ 
        c_type_FC callback = /* get member function BaseClass::methodCallback from object stored in hashpmap childHashTable[childClassName]*/ ;
        /* lib_function is the function I have to pass the pointer to */
        lib_function(input_1, ..., callback);
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> > childbHashTable;
}
```

### Attempted Solution

I coudl get a workaroud solution using class templates creating a static std::function implementation but requires a lots of line of code for **each** ChilClass_n:

```
template <typename T>
struct CB_capab;
template <typename Ret, typename... Params>
struct CB_capab<Ret(Params...)> {
    template <typename... Args>
    static Ret callback(Args... args) {
        func(args...);
    }
    static std::function<Ret(Params...)> func;
};
template <typename Ret, typename... Params>
std::function<Ret(Params...)> CB_capab<Ret(Params...)>::func;
```

And is implemented like this in the *createMacaroni*-method using std::bind :

```
CB_capab<UA_StatusCode(lib_type, ... lib_type)> myClassTemplate;
myClassTemplate.func = std::bind(&BaseClass::methodCallback, capabHashTable[childClassName], std::placeholders::_1, ..., std::placeholders::_11);
lib_returnType local_cb = static_cast<lib_returnType>(myClassTemplate.callback);
```

This is very bad as it requires a lots of lines of code for each of the 10^2 childClass.

## Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `std::function` is the answer. Or 42. This also looks a lot like a factory, which is a well-known pattern with lots of solutions.

Comment: Doesn't `lib_function` provide `void* user_data` in addition to `callback` ?

Comment: BTW, I don't see any repetition for you childClass...(Only for each type of callback).

Comment: Similar to your solution, with `static BaseClass* ptr_for_callback = nullptr;`, and `lib_returnType myMethodCallback(lib_type input_1, ..., lib_type input_11) { return ptr_for_callback->methodCallback(input_1, ..., input_11); }` You may do `ptr_for_callback = childHashTable[childClassName].get(); lib_returnType local_cb = myMethodCallback;`

Comment: @Jarod42 `lib_function` does not provides a `void* user_data` pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the library I was using was the open62541 [stack](https://github.com/open62541/open62541), and the function that received the C-function pointer was the *UA_Server_addMethodNode* (in the original question called *lib_function*).

As @bobshowrocks (and in the comments @Jarod42) mentioned, I solved the issue using a `void *methodContext` pointer that was not set at any point (equvalent to the void *user_data pointer) and with an extra static member function inside BaseClass. I also had to modify something inside my ImplementationClass.h so that the hash map did not got out of scope.

So the **BaseClass.h** turned to (added one extra static member function):

```
Class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual UA_StatusCode capabilityImplementation(/* same inputs as staticMethodCallback */) = 0;

    bool performLocalCheckFct(...){ /* perform check */ }

    UA_StatusCode methodCallback(/* same inputs as staticMethodCallback */)
    {
        if(performLocalCheckFct(...)== true)
        {
            return capabilityImplementation(input_1, ..., input_11);
        }
    }

    static UA_StatusCode staticMethodCallback(UA_Server *server,
                                              const UA_NodeId *sessionId, void *sessionContext,
                                              const UA_NodeId *methodId, void *methodContext,
                                              const UA_NodeId *objectId, void *objectContext,
                                              size_t inputSize, const UA_Variant *input,
                                              size_t outputSize, UA_Variant *output)
    {
        BaseClass* ptr = static_cast<BaseClass *>(methodContext);
        ptr->methodCallback(server, sessionId, sessionContext, methodId, NULL, objectId, objectContext, inputSize, input, outputSize, output);
    }
    /* something else */
protected:
    /* some data */
}
```

And it was implemented in the **ImplementationClass.h** as:

```
Class HandlerClass{
public:
    HandlerClass(lib_type input_1){
        initializeHashMap();
        /* do something else */
    }

    initializeHashMap(){
        childHashTable["myChild1"] = std::make_shared<ChildClass_1>();
        /*... e.g. 50 different child classes */
        childHashTable["myChild50"] = std::make_shared<ChildClass_50>();
    }

    bool createMacaroni(std::string childClassName) {
        /* do stuff */
        /* Get the respective pointer of object to refer the callback */
        BaseClass* ptr_for_callback = capabHashTable[childClassName].get();

        /* Define the function callback */
        UA_MethodCallback local_cb = &BaseClass::staticMethodCallback;

        /* lib_function is the function I have to pass the pointer to */
        UA_Server_addMethodNode(input_1, ..., local_cb, ..., ptr_for_callback, ..., input_11);
    }

private:
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> > childbHashTable;
}

std::unordered_map< std::string, std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> > HandlerClass::capabHashTable;
```

Note the static definition of the hash map inside the class and the respective external definition in the aim to avoid global variables.

Thanks again to @Jarod42 and @bobshowrocks

Answer (score 2):

To call a non-static member function in C++ two bits of information are needed, the address of the member function to call and the address of the object that is calling the function. Where as a C function (or a free function in C++) just needs the address of the function. This means that you can't collapse a non-static member function down into a function pointer.

This doesn't mean what you want to do is impossible. Typically C libraries that take in function pointers also take in a pointer to user data that will be passed into the pointed to function when it is called. You can use this to pass a pointer to the object. You can use either free functions or static member functions for this purpose. Below is a rough example of how it could be done.

```
// This would be the callback function signature your library is expecting
void typedef (* callback)(void * userState, int data);

class Foo
{
    // Your original member function you want to call
    void doSomething(int data) { /* stuff */ }

    // The static member function that can be passed around as a function pointer
    static void wrapDoSomething(void * userState, int data)
    {
        Foo * ptr = static_cast<Foo *>(userState);
        ptr->doSomething(data);
    }

    // Your way to have the object register a callback
    void registerCallback()
    {
        lib_register_function(&Foo::wrapDoSomething, this);
    }
};
```

In this example `wrapDoSomething()` and `registerCallback()` don't have to be member functions. And none of the functions here need to be public strictly speaking, but it would make sense for your equivalent of `doSomething()` to be public since it's ultimately being called from outside the class.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` should be `static_cast` instead

Comment: And OP's version works (in single thread only because of the global). Without userdata, OP uses a global which allows to store the instance. (OP uses `std::function` which has the instance).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Quite correct, thanks for catching that.

Comment: @Jarod42 I agree that OP's solution will work, but in a very limited situation. The the question doesn't give any specifics about the library they are using, and they described their solution as "very bad". In hopes of providing a reasonable answer I made some assumptions (that the C library would allow passing state into the callback via a pointer). If my assumption is false I'm not sure that there is a general answer much beyond what OP has already posted.

Comment: Thanks @bobshowrocks, you pointed me exactly to the right direction. I just solved the issue, will post the answer below.

Comment: @Jarod42 I also used what you contributed in the comments in the question post, thanks a lot too